# How to create a bundle

Tags: iphone, bundle, resourcebundle

how do I create a bundle with resources like images and xibs to share it between apps? I saw that there's a way to do it when creating a new project, but there must be a way to do it based on a finished project, right?

Thanks in advance
–f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iPhoneOS the bundle structure is very simple. Just a make folder and put all the resources under it.

```
blah.bundle/
  foo.png
  bar.png
  baz.nib
  ...
```

But apps are sandboxed so the same bundle must be copied into each app.

Comment: Ok, cool. But how do I reference it when it comes to methods like `–initWithNibName:bundle:` where I want to use `NSBundle`s `-bundleWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: @flohei: You can use `+bundleWithPath:`.